# TikZ plots get recompiled every time when using tikzscale

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, matlab2tikz, tikzscale

For my thesis I have a lot of Ti*k*Z plots exported from Matlab using the `matlab2tikz` library.

I want to use the `tikzscale` package together with externalization of the plots to save compiling time. Using externalization is recommended in the `tikzscale` documentation but does not work as expected.

Plots included via `\includegraphics` to make use of the `tikzscale` are recompiled with every `pdflatex` run, even if the figure is not changed, this is not the expected behaviour and causes the compiling time to become even longer.

Plots included via `\input`, so not making use of the `tikzscale`, features are not recompiled, this is what I expect.

Am I doing something wrong during the export with `matlab2tikz` or with including the `.tikz` files with `\includegraphics` or is this a bug of the `tikzscale` package?

I need the additional scaling features of `tikzscale`, so I cannot simply avoid the `tikzscale` package.

> Setup: WIN7+TexLive2014 / Ubuntu 14.04+TexLive2013, behaviour is the same on both systems

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzTest/] 
\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\tikzsetnextfilename{test}
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{tikzTest/test.tikz}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\setlength\figureheight{0.75\textwidth} 
\setlength\figurewidth{0.75\textwidth}
\tikzsetnextfilename{test2}
\input{tikzTest/test2.tikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Matlab export

```
x = linspace(0,10,11);
y = x.^2;
figure(1);
plot(x,y);
cleanfigure;
%prepare figure to be included with tikzscale and \includegraphics
matlab2tikz('<pathToTexFolder>\tikzTest\Test.tikz','noSize',true,'extraTikzpictureOptions','trim axis left, trim axis right');
%prepare figure to be included with \input
matlab2tikz('<pathToTexFolder>\tikzTest\Test2.tikz','height','\figureheight','width','\figurewidth');
```

**`test.tikz`**

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
% Minimal pgfplots version: 1.3
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
trim axis left, trim axis right
]

\begin{axis}[%
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=10,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=100
]
\addplot [color=black,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
1   1\\
2   4\\
3   9\\
4   16\\
5   25\\
6   36\\
7   49\\
8   64\\
9   81\\
10  100\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

**`test2.tikz`**

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
% Minimal pgfplots version: 1.3
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.95092\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=10,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=100
]
\addplot [color=black,solid,forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
1   1\\
2   4\\
3   9\\
4   16\\
5   25\\
6   36\\
7   49\\
8   64\\
9   81\\
10  100\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: Plan B: `external/export next=false`

Comment: when using external/export next =false, will this only omit creating external pdfs while already exported pdfs (from a previous run) will still be included in the document or will the pdf not be used at all?

Comment: Experiments shows that Ti*k*Z love compiling pictures... you can only turn it on but cannot stop it. In case `export next=false`, Ti*k*Z will leave the external PDFs there and **recompile** pictures again per compilation. Probability you need a complex macro to include those pictures and comment out the `tikzpicture` yourself. (Will this is plan B--)

Comment: @Symbol Thanks for your comment, this was what I was afraid of.
Still I can't really believe that `\tikzcale` documentation encourages the user to use externalization because of faster compiling times but does not avoid recompiling tikz-pictures. Either I implemented it wrong or there is a bug in the `\tikzscale` package

Comment: Problem still persists, opened a bug report at [tikzscale github](https://github.com/MagicMuscleMan/tikzscale/issues/3)

Comment: @roteiro Try to *minimise* your example. Can the problem not be reproduced with simpler plots or smaller plots? You want *just enough* to create the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I just realized this question was asked 2 years ago...

Have you tried using LuaLaTeX with `tikzexternalcheckshellescape`? It worked for me before.

Try with the above preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzsetexternalprefix{figurescache/} %folder for temp figures
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -shell-escape -synctex=1 -halt-on-error -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\begin{document}
[Tikz stuff in here]
\end{document}
```

And then to compile your document, type:

```
lualatex filename.tex
```

After this, a filename `filename.makefile` will be created and type

```
make -f filename.makefile
```

then another

```
lualatex filename.tex
```

Comment: This is rather a comment because you ask OP to do something or you can also do this and show the results to make a self contained answer.